# How to run the batch file commands sequential?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to call the 2 batch files in another batch file.But the batch files are running parallel. I want to run those batch files one after another.

Please provide the solution if any?

Answer (score 1):

```
call batch1.cmd
call batch2.cmd
```

There you go.

Comment: First batch file is running some seconds and before completing the first batch file, second batch file is running some seconds then again first batch file is running.